# How do you turn a string "04L " into "04" and "L"?

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

It's been nearly four decades since I wrote much Fortran code. If I have a string:

```
"04L       "
```

How do I extract the numeric part (always 2 digits), the single letter, and ignore trailing whitespace?  I want to end up with two strings, `"04"` and `"L"`.

I'm modifying a Fortran 90 program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use indexing: `str(1:2)` are the first two chars, `str(3:3)` would be the third one. Here is a minimum example:

```
program test
  character(len=*),parameter :: str = "04L       "

  print *,str(1:2)
  print *,str(3:3)
end program
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderVogt!  I'll accept the answer when 6 minutes more are up.  It worked.  I guess I was thinking in terms of regular expressions at first, then I realized simple substring would do.